# Can I upload a file from the user's browser directly to Azure Blob Storage using a Blazor Server application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, blazor-server-side

I am hosting a Blazor Server web application on an Azure App Service.  Users can upload files to an Azure Blob Storage account.  I generate a token and build a URI for the upload.  Following most every article I have read, I am copying the file from the user's PC to the web application in either a MemoryStream or FileStream, then uploading the file from the web application to the Blob Storage using Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient.Upload().

This two-step process is slow and inefficient as the file is being uploaded twice, once to the Azure App Service, and again to the Blob Storage.

I would like for a user to be able to upload directly to the Blob Storage, using Azure.Storage.Blobs so that I can use a Progress Handler to update a progress bar.

I have watched videos, read articles, and everything seems to point to Microsoft articles that provide an example similar to what I have done.  I have read articles about using javascript, but I could not get any solutions to work with Blazor.  Below is a simplified version of my code.

```
    public static async Task UploadFileToAzureBlobStorage(IBrowserFile fileToUpload, Progress<long> progressHandler, Progress<long> copyProgressHandler)
    {
        // Create URL
        Uri blobUri = new Uri($"https://storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/containerName/filename.txt?token");

        // Create blob client from URL
        BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(blobUri);

        // Resolve full path to file
        string filename = Path.Combine("folderName", "filename.txt");

        // Upload file
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
        try
        {
            // Upload file to web server
            await fileToUpload.OpenReadStream(fileToUpload.Size).CopyToAsync(stream, copyProgressHandler);
            
            // Upload file from web server to Azure blob storage
            stream.Position = 0;
            await Task.Run(() => blobClient.Upload(stream, progressHandler: progressHandler));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Error handling
        }

        // Dispose of stream
        await stream.DisposeAsync();
    }
```

Comment: *but I could not get any solutions to work with Blazor. Below is a simplified version of my code.* What happens if you run the code?

Comment: Progress bar makes sense for big files. You can read the stream of the files in chunks and  upload it and update the progress bar.

Comment: `This two-step process is slow and inefficient as the file is being uploaded twice, once to the Azure App Service, and again to the Blob Storage.` that's done by the code itself. Have you tried `await blobClient.UploadAsync(inputFile.OpenReadStream(..)` ?

Comment: To make this even faster you'd have to upload directly from the browser using JavaScript and a SAS token

Comment: @PeterBons, my code executes properly and the file is uploaded, but it first uploads to the web server, then to the Azure Blob Storage.  I would like a solution where the file uploads directly to Blob Storage.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I believe you are correct that the solution is javascript-based, but I cannot find any solution that works with a Blazor Server App.  Any help with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was ultimately able to solve this issue by using the Azure Blob Storage client library for Node.js.  While there were some challenges in communicating between the node.js application and the Blazor server, I found solutions for each challenge and now have a solution that uploads a file of any size from the user's browser to the Azure Storage, with a progress bar.

Here's what I did:

1. Created a folder in the project's root folder named `NodeJsLibraries`.
2. Right-click the new folder and open in Terminal.
3. Type in a command to create a `package.json` file that will store the information and dependencies of the npm project:

   ```
   npm init
   ```
4. Hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on all prompts, accepting the defaults.
5. Installed the Azure Storage Blob package with this command:

   ```
   npm install @azure/storage-blob
   ```
6. Created a sub folder named `src` in the `NodeJsLibraries` folder.
7. In the `src` sub folder, created a JavaScript file named `index.js`.  Here is my JavaCcript:

   ```js
   const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');

   window.UploadFile = async function(accountName, sasToken, containerName, blobName, inputElement, fileNumber, fileUploadId) {
       // Reset cancelUpload flag
       window.cancelUpload = false;
       return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
           try {
               // Resolve file element
               let file = inputElement.files[fileNumber];
               const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net?${sasToken}`);
               const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
               const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
               const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.uploadData(file, {
                   blockSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4MB blocks
                   onProgress: (progress) => {
                       // Check if a cancellation has been requested
                       if (window.cancelUpload) {
                           reject('Upload cancelled');
                           return;
                       }

                       // Report the upload progress to the UI
                       window.DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('<project_name>', '<project_name>.JavaScriptEvents.UpdateProgress', progress.loadedBytes, fileUploadId);
                   }
               });
               console.log(`Upload block blob ${blobName} successfully`, uploadBlobResponse.requestId);
               resolve(uploadBlobResponse);
           } catch (error) {
               reject(error);
           }
       });
   };

   window.requestUploadCancellation = function () {
       window.cancelUpload = true;
   };
   ```
8. Installed `webpack` and `webpack-cli` as dev dependencies by running the following in the `NodeJsLibraries` folder. (This will allow you to use `webpack` to bundle your JavaScript code and dependencies):

   ```
   npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev
   ```
9. Created a file in the `NodeJsLibraries` folder named `webpack.config.js` and configured webpack to output the bundled file into the `wwwroot/js` folder of my Blazor project.  This is the file content:

   ```
   const path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
      entry: './src/index.js',
      output: {
        filename: 'azure_blob.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../wwwroot/js'),
        library: 'AzureBlob'
      }
    };
   ```
10. Edit the `package.json` file, adding the following inside the `<script>` tags:

    ```json
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
    ```
11. Added a reference to the `azure_blob.js` file in the `_Host.cshtml` file:

    ```html
    <script src="js/azure_blob.js"></script>
    ```
12. Bundled my JavaScript code and dependencies into a single file named `azure_blob.js` in the `wwwroot/js` folder using this command. (NOTE: Anytime you change the `index.js` file, you must re-run this command):

    ```
    npm run build
    ```
13. Created a `static` class named `JavaScriptEvents` with methods `UpdateProgress()`, which is called by the JavaScript, and `GetProgress()`, which is called by my upload code to find out how many bytes have been loaded.  I assign a unique `FileId` for each upload, which is parsed to the JavaScript, and used to track different file uploads in different sessions.
14. In Blazor, we can access the `IBrowserFile` object for uploading a file.  This object cannot be parsed to node.js as it's a .NET type that is not recognized.  Instead, I created a reference to the `InputFile` element and parsed that reference along with the file # (if multiple files were selected) which node.js can handle.

    HTML:

    ```html
    <InputFile id="file" @ref="uploadFile" OnChange="UploadFileAsync" />
    ```

    Declaration in my class:

    ```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Reference to inputFile element; used by node.js to resolve file for upload (IBrowserFile object cannot be parsed via javascript interop as it's not recognized by node.js)
    /// </summary>
    InputFile uploadFile;
    ```
15. This code is used in my `Upload()` method.  A `CancellationToken` is created and referenced when calling the JavaScript via the JavaScript runtime; this is done to prevent a timeout of 60 seconds from cancelling the task if the upload takes more than a minute.

    ```cs
            // Start stopwatch to time
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();            
     var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Task uploadTask = this.jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync(
            "UploadFile",
            cancellationTokenSource.Token,
            this.azureSas.StorageAccount,
            this.azureSas.Token,
            this.azureSas.ContainerName,
            blobName,
            inputFileElement, // Reference to the InputFile element
                0, // 0 = the file # in the list of files selected
                fileUploadId).AsTask();
                while (true)
                {
                    // Wait for either the upload task to complete or a short delay
                    TimeSpan timeElapsed = stopwatch.Elapsed;
                    Task completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(uploadTask, this.UpdateProgressAsync(fileUploadId, filesize, timeElapsed.TotalSeconds)).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    // If the upload task completed, exit the loop
                    if (completedTask == uploadTask)
                    {
                        Debug.Print($"Upload is complete: {uploadTask.IsCompleted} {uploadTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully} {uploadTask.Status}");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Handle the result or exception of the task
                if (uploadTask.IsFaulted)
                {
                    this.errorText = uploadTask.Exception?.InnerException?.Message ?? "Unknown error";
                    if (this.errorText == "Upload cancelled")
                    {
                        this.progress = string.Empty;
                        this.uploadStatus = "Upload cancelled by user";
                    }

                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                this.errorText = exception.Message;
                return;
            }

            this.uploadStatus = "Upload complete";
    ```
16. Here's the method for updating progress:

    ```cs
    private async Task UpdateProgressAsync(string fileUploadId, long fileSize, double secondsElapsed)

    {
            long bytesUploaded = JavaScriptEvents.GetProgress(fileUploadId);

        // When bytes uploaded are 1 or more, change the upload status to "Uploading..."
        if (bytesUploaded > 0 && this.uploadStatus != "Uploading...")
        {
            this.uploadStatus = "Uploading...";
        }

        // Create string with MB/s upload speed
        string speed = CommonMethods.SizeSuffix((long)(bytesUploaded / secondsElapsed)) + "/s";

        // Create string to display percentage uploaded
        this.progress = (long)((bytesUploaded / (double)fileSize) * 100) + "%        " + speed  + "        " + CommonMethods.SizeSuffix(bytesUploaded) + "/" + CommonMethods.SizeSuffix(fileSize);

        // Refresh the UI to display progress
        await InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);

        await Task.Delay(500).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    ```
17. I also added a Cancel button that calls this method:

    ```cs
    private async Task CancelUpload()
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("requestUploadCancellation");
    }
    ```

I hope this helps someone else that wants to upload large files to Azure Storage from a Blazor Server application without following Microsoft's recommendations, which results in the file being copied to the server first, then being uploaded to Azure Storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload file to Azure Blob storage through your Blazor web app, I  think you have to upload to your web app first then push the file to Azure Blob, even if you upload the file directly in Azure portal, it also executes a middle step, like we know we need to have a file storage server, only if we upload to that server directly(maybe via ftp) we could realize your requirement. What we see in the Azure portal is also a web application. So it's upload to the web app then that web app push the file to Blob. For Azure Blob, it provides us with API or SDK to help in developing, so we have to do the "upload to application first" operation.

If I misunderstood your requirement pls point it out. Then for uploading files in a blazor server application, please take a look at [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0). For the large file upload, pay attention to [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0#file-size-read-and-upload-limits).

By the way, I'm not very sure if you got exception in your code but it looks good as far as I know. I also had an sample in my side, and you might take a look at it if your code doesn't work.

```
@using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
@using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

<p>
    <label>
        <InputFile OnChange="@OnInputFileChange" />
    </label>
</p>

@code {
    private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var file = e.GetMultipleFiles()[0];
        var name = file.Name;
        var type = file.ContentType;

        var connectionstring = "connection_string";
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionstring);
        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("container_name");
        await blobContainerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        BlobClient blobClent = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(name);
        BlobHttpHeaders httpheaders = new BlobHttpHeaders()
            {
                ContentType = type
            };
        var res = await blobClent.UploadAsync(file.OpenReadStream(), httpheaders);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Tiny.  I have read those Microsoft articles, and actually modeled my code after them, but I believe there must be a better way to upload a file rather than uploading it twice.  On larger files, doubling the time it takes is very noticeable.  When downloading from Azure Storage, a URL is generated and users download directly from Blob Storage; I would like them to also directly upload.  As Panagiotis Kanavos suggested above, perhaps there is a javascript-based solution that does this and works with Blazor server apps.

Comment: thank you Eric for your kind reply and let's see if Panagiotis could come back to offer that kind of solution. I also wonder about it.